# replace '_' with ',' in a file which contains list of filenames

Tags: shell-script, shell, text-processing, awk

It will be helpful for me if someone could help to write a shell script to meet the following requirement.

I have a text file which contains list of filenames as shown below:

```
ADB_AR_2006_07.pdf
ADBL_AR_2010_11.pdf
CBL_AR_2013_14.pdf
CZBIL_AR_2007_08.pdf
BOKL_AR_2015_16.pdf
..
..
```

Now I want to replace the first and second '_' with ',' for all the filenames listed in the text file.So that the filenames become:

```
ADB,AR,2006_07.pdf
ADBL,AR,2010_11.pdf
CBL,AR,2013_14.pdf
CZBIL,AR,2007_08.pdf
BOKL,AR,2015_16.pdf
..
..
```

Comment: you don't need shell scripts for this... just a simple search and replace with `sed`... see https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/sed/info if you need resources to learn sed

Answer (score 5):

You could use a simple ***sed*** expression:

```
sed -Ei 's/^([^_]+)_([^_]+)_/\1,\2,/' file
```

---

`file` contents after modification:

```
ADB,AR,2006_07.pdf
ADBL,AR,2010_11.pdf
CBL,AR,2013_14.pdf
CZBIL,AR,2007_08.pdf
BOKL,AR,2015_16.pdf
```

---

- `i` - allows in-place file modification
- `-E` - allows extended regular expressions

---

A simplified approach would look as:

```
sed -i 's/_/,/; s/_/,/' file
```

Comment: just follow what OP stated `replace the first and second '_' with ','` ... `sed 's/_/,/; s/_/,/'`

Comment: @Sundeep, could be a good simplified alternative, you may post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Simple python script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    for line in f:
        tokens=line.strip().split('_')
        print(",".join(tokens[0:3]),'_',tokens[3],sep='')
```

The key idea is that we read the file line by line, break it down into parts at `_` separator, and join first 3 items with `_` into a string using the slice notation `[0:3]`. If you need  to save that output as file, use `>` shell operator and send output to a file.

Test:

```
$ ./edit_lines.py input.txt                                                                                                                                                             
ADB,AR,2006_07.pdf
ADBL,AR,2010_11.pdf
CBL,AR,2013_14.pdf
CZBIL,AR,2007_08.pdf
BOKL,AR,2015_16.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution with `awk`:

```
$ awk -F"_" '{ print $1","$2","$3"_"$4}' list 
ADB,AR,2006_07.pdf
ADBL,AR,2010_11.pdf
CBL,AR,2013_14.pdf
CZBIL,AR,2007_08.pdf
BOKL,AR,2015_16.pdf
```